# Is there an alternative to Update for continuously spawning an object?

Tags: unity, c#

What I did here works, but it looks messy and funny to me.

```
void Update()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if(BossHP <= 2)
    {
        PhaseTwo.Invoke();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Circle"))
    {
        BossHP--;
        Debug.Log(BossHP);
    }
}
```

When I put `if(BossHP <= 2)  { PhaseTwo.Invoke(); }` under `void OnTriggerEnter2D`, it only spawns once. So that's why I put under Update. But ...is this the right way? It looks funny to me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's only invoking `PhaseTwo` once is likely because the circle continues overlapping this script's object. `OnTriggerEnter2D` won't get called again for this pair of colliders until the colliders separate and then overlap again.

If you want to continuously invoke this event every frame after reaching this threshold health, an alternative would be to start a coroutine:

```
const int LOW_HEALTH_THRESHOLD = 2;
Coroutine _lowHealthLoop;

private IEnumerator LowHealth() {
    while (BossHP < LOW_HEALTH_THRESHOLD) {
        PhaseTwo.Invoke();
        yield return null;
    }
    _lowHealthLoop = null;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Circle"))
    {
        BossHP--;
        Debug.Log(BossHP);

        if (BossHP < LOW_HEALTH_THRESHOLD && _lowHealthLoop == null) {
            _lowHealthLoop = StartCoroutine(LowHealth());
        }
    }
}
```